# how to link to WebMethod when using jQuery treeview?

Tags: jquery, treeview

I'm using jQuery treeview plugin to populate a child treeview once click a folder node to expand. but $("#tv").treeview({url: webservice/webmethod}); but doesn't work, and failed to call webthod. How to make it? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this: http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/ ?

Comment: thanks a lot. url(..) doesn't work for webmethod. i used .ajax and it works.

Comment: @Elain - can you please provide an example of how you used .ajax?  I'm having the same issue with this plugin.